# show progress and refresh gridview after operation

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have an operation that scans folders in selected directory, gets all the files, parse them and add to SQLite db. As you can guess it takes a while when directory has many files. 
First user clicks on button to open folder picker, after acceptation message from MessageDialog the action is performed.

On same site there is GridView with elements in DB.

Now I want to:
1) show progress using ProgressRing
2) Reload GridView with new data (the old one + the new one) after scanning directory

I've tried simply hide GridView, show ProgressRing and the turn on GridView again but when app is scanning everything it looks like it is freezed or something.

How can I achive my goal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you run your database operations on a background thread.